# Existing images disappear from carousel when uploading a new image

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-file-upload

Why does the ng-model images(data) get deleted when I upload a new image? The carousel 'looses' all the photos and shows nothing.

The upload button:

```
<button style="text-align:center; margin-left: 50%; transform:translateX(-50%); margin-top: 40px; color: 2d5d82" 
      ngf-select="" 
      class="btn btn-lg"
      ng-model="$parent.files" 
      ng-model-rejected="rejFiles" 
      ngf-drag-over-class="{accept:'dragover', reject:'dragover-err', delay:100}" 
      ngf-multiple="true" 
      ngf-resize="{width: 400, height: 250, centerCrop: true}"
      ngf-validate="{size: {max: '20MB', min: '10B'}, height: {max: 12000}, width: {max: 12000}}"
      ngf-allow-dir="true" 
      ngf-keep="true"
      ngf-accept="'image/*,application/pdf'" 
      ngf-drop-available="dropAvailable" 
      ngf-capture="camera"  
      Click here to upload pictures 
</button>
```

Main image carousel:

```
<div>
    <uib-carousel  no-wrap="WrapSlides" style="max-height: 330px;">
          <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in files" id="carousel-custom" active="slide.active" style="width:80%; max-height: 300px;">
               <img ng-src="{{slide.image_path}}" style="margin:0px; max-height: 300px;  width:auto; height: auto; margin-left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); z-index: 0;" >
               <img style="margin-left: 50%; transform:translateX(-50%); top:0px;  width: 25px; cursor:pointer; z-index: 50;" ng-click="delete_image(slide)" ng-src="{{image.src.del_image}}">
           </uib-slide>
    </uib-carousel>
</div>
```

Bitmaps of carousel:

```
<td ng-repeat='slide in count = (files) track by $index' data-target='#carousel-custom' ng-click="update_carousel($index)" style="min-height:60px; max-height: 60px; height:60px !important; width:auto; display:inline-block; padding:0px; margin: 0px; " ng-class="{ active: isActive(slide) }" class="ng-scope">
     <img ng-src="{{slide.image_path}}" alt='' style="width:auto; min-height:60px; max-height: 60px; height:60px !important; cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px; "/>
</td>
```

All that changes in the model when uploading a new image, is active gets added to array of images:

```
...,{"active":false}]
```

Comment: Where the image_path come from?

Comment: image_path is the db field containing url to image, have date etc aswell. Could this be causing the  problem? Should I rather make a new array with only the urls? @danial

Comment: You are showing the image_path with ng-src so it is like showing server urls and if they are disappearing you are probably removing them or they become invalid or something, so it doesn't have much to do with the ng-file-upload plugin, but showing the urls from server on the front-end.